# How to restrict access to single API method with IP security or some other option

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, web-config, iis-7.5

I wanted to know how to restrict one WEB API method to be called from single IP by IIS or web.config. My application developed with ASP.NET WEB API. I can't make code changes at this moment(to add IPFilter as Attribute or CORS implementation )

Regards,
Srikanth

Comment: Add a URL Rewrite rule then.

Comment: can you please help to write a rewrite rule for this kind of requirement. I have not much exposure on rules. Please help me.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module You can get started from there. Choose the URL pattern you want to protect, add a condition to check incoming IP address, and then abort all unwanted requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IIS "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" option to Allow/deny the site/API to specific IP .

In windows 10 this applet can be installed from the

Control Panel-> turn Windows Feature On or off -> Internet Information Server-> World Web Services->Security-> IP Security

In Windows server it can be enabled from the "Server Manager".

Refer below for the details.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831785(v=ws.11)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions

[image: Server manager]

[image: Domain Restriction Applet]

[image: Allow IP]